# Conversion functions, std::is_base_of and spurious incomplete types: substitution failure IS an error

Tags: c++, c++17, sfinae, type-traits, conversion-operator

I'm attempting to implement a conversion function operator, and use std::is_base_of to limit the scope of applicability, but I'm running into issues.

```
#include <type_traits>

class Spurious;

class MyClassBase {};

template< typename T >
class MyClass: public MyClassBase {
public:
    template< typename U, std::enable_if_t< std::is_base_of<MyClassBase, U>::value, bool> = true >
    operator U () const {
        return U{}; // Complex initialization omitted for brevity
    }
};

class MyBool: public MyClass< bool > {};
class MyInt: public MyClass< int > {};

int do_stuff( int i, Spurious const & obj);
int do_stuff( int i, MyBool const & obj) {
    return i;
}

int main() {
    MyInt const obj;
    return do_stuff( 3, obj );
}
```

The presence of Spurious and the related function definitions means that I'm getting compiler errors ([compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/8j7cYv368); GCC: `error: invalid use of incomplete type 'const class Spurious'` Clang:`error: incomplete type 'Spurious' used in type trait expression`) in the is_base_of implementation.

I get why you can't is_base_of an incomplete type, but I'm not quite understanding why "substitution failure is not an error" isn't applicable here. I would have thought that attempting to is_base_of an incomplete type during template expansion would cause the compiler to just abort the conversion attempt and move on to the next function definition. That's sort of the entire point of the is_base_of statement here: ignore classes which don't match the pattern.

My main question, though, is not the "why", but the "what next". Are there any workarounds? Is there some way to ignore things like Spurious while not requiring them to be fully defined within this compilation unit? Ideally, I'd be able to just modify the definition of the conversion operator (e.g. the SFINAE template parameters) to get it to work.

Comment: SFINAE isn't applicable with incomplete types because you wouldn't want _statically evaluated expressions_ like `is_base_of` to return different values based on things that may change externally. For example, two different sources may include this code as a header -- and the order of inclusions _may_ provide the definition of `Spurious`. And then suddenly your evaluation order may change. What if `Spurious` _does_ inherit from `MyClassBase`? The source that has the definition suddenly will get an ambiguity error, but the incomplete one wouldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn’t SFINAE, which certainly **applies** to incomplete types:

```
template<class T,bool=false>
struct size : std::integral_constant<std::size_t,0> {};
template<class T>
struct size<T,!sizeof(T)> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t,sizeof(T)> {};
static_assert(size<char>::value==1);  // OK

struct A;
static_assert(size<A>::value==0);  // OK
struct A {};
static_assert(size<A>::value==0);  // OK!
```

The issue here is that `std::is_base_of` has “undefined behavior” (read: use of it makes a program **ill-formed**, no diagnostic required) if both types are non-union class types and the latter is incomplete.  This isn’t covered by SFINAE both because it’s not in the **immediate** context and because it’s NDR.

These compilers are choosing to reject the code, which has the benefit of preventing **surprises** like the `// OK!` above.

You can use the direct SFINAE approach to **avoid** this problem:

```
template< typename T >
class MyClass: public MyClassBase {
public:
    template< typename U, std::enable_if_t<
        (sizeof(U), std::is_base_of<MyClassBase, U>::value), bool> = true >
    operator U () const {
        return U{}; // Complex initialization omitted for brevity
    }
};
```

Here there is a direct substitution error in the type of the template parameter if `U` is incomplete, which **prevents** instantiating the `std::is_base_of` specialization that would be IFNDR.  Note that using incomplete types with SFINAE this way is still rather **dangerous**, because the same specialization instantiated in a context where the types in question are complete might produce different behavior (which is *also* IFNDR, per [temp.point]/7).

Comment: The code you supplied doesn't compile because the second `size` definition should be a partial specialization. But even defining it as `size<T,!sizeof(T)>` fails with gcc for _"template argument '! sizeof (T)' involves template parameter(s)"_ ([source](https://godbolt.org/z/89ze35zhh)). I don't believe there is any way for you to detect whether a type `T` is incomplete at all -- since the language is not required to return a value for `sizeof` incomplete types. If you could detect it, then this would violate ODR by defining `size<A>` with two different values at compile-time

Comment: @Human-Compiler: The most current versions of GCC and Clang accept it (after the trivial fix).  We can use `decltype` to make it unambiguously acceptable; the ODR problems are very real, but they don’t make it ill-formed.

Comment: Would you happen to have any references on a `decltype(sizeof(<incomplete type>))` being well-formed? My understanding is that the `sizeof(<incomplete type>)` is ill-formed, and so even a `decltype` is ill-formed (not SFINAE-compatible). The C++ standard states for [\[expr.sizeof\]/1](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.sizeof#1) that it cannot be applied to incomplete types -- not that it must conditionally not return a value. Is there a separate passage somewhere that makes this SFINAE-friendly that I'm not aware of?

Comment: @Human-Compiler: It’s SFINAEable *because* it’s ill-formed ([temp.deduct.general]/8, although the list of reasons in /11 pertains only to invalid *types*).

Comment: I'm still not fully understanding why SFINAE doesn't apply. I can kinda understand that explicit undefined behavior "outranks" SFINAE, but I'm not getting your immediate context/NDR comment. -- Anyway, the main question of "what next" is still unresolved. Particularly if is_base_of can invoke nasal demons if you're not ultra-certain about which types actually will get fed to it, which seems to make it dangerous to use in templated contexts.

Comment: @R.M.: The error doesn’t occur during *substitution* into `std::is_base_of<MyClassBase,U>::value`: the resulting expression with `U`=`Spurious` is *prima facie* valid.  It’s just that when trying to find the value of that expression, something like a `static_assert` is hit in the **definition** of `std::is_base_of`.  That’s the “immediate context” distinction.  I’ll make the workaround a bit more explicit.